# How do I hide the location indicator in Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: indicator, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell, panel, notification-area

I want to get rid of the Location indicator that appears in the notification area of the GNOME Panel. I have disabled location services in the Settings menu, yet the indicator is still shown.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did it by removing `geoip-database` and `geoclue-2.0`.
It also asks to remove the `gnome-maps` and `gnome-weather` due to dependencies issues.

Comment: I think OP is asking for a purely aesthetic modification, not removing libraries.

Comment: There's an app (extendion) for that: [Location Icon Autohide](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1274/location-icon-autohide/) as mentioned by @pomsky

Answer (score 1):

There's a new extension available now which does the job: [Location Icon Autohide](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1274/location-icon-autohide/).