# Any way to use Maximus-two (or similar extension) on Gnome 3.24 in 17.04?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-shell

For the last few versions, Maximus-Two was not available to install from extensions.gnome.org, but I always found workarounds to install it anyway and it worked. However this time around I haven't found any way to make it work, and haven't had more luck with MaximusNG or other similar extensions.

Pixel Saver works, but I don't want window buttons in my panel so I'd rather have a Maximus-style extension that just removes the title bar from maximized windows if possible.

Thanks in advance to anyone who might have a way to help me !

Comment: I don't know how active development is, but there is an issue open for MaximusNG here: https://github.com/luispabon/maximus-gnome-shell/issues/25

Comment: Your second query about the GPS icon has already been asked and answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/903381/how-do-i-hide-the-location-indicator-in-ubuntu-gnome

Answer (score 0):

There is a new extension named [No Title Bar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1267/no-title-bar/) available now.

It's a fork of Pixel Saver with advanced options like **disabling/theming** window buttons, **whitelist/blacklist** of applications etc.

(Info courtesy of [@d3vid](https://askubuntu.com/users/7146/d3vid))

Alternatively, you can tweak Pixel Saver to get rid of the window buttons from the top bar following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/948321/480481).