# How do I hide/disable close buttons for GNOME windows?

Tags: gnome, titlebar, window-buttons, maximized, window-decoration

I am using the [Pixel Saver extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/) for GNOME Shell, similar to the old Maximus extension for GNOME 2 / Unity. When I maximise a window, the title and menu bars are hidden.

But I don't want the minimise, maximise or close buttons to appear in the Activity Bar. [Instead of messing with window buttons itself, Pixel Saver honours the GNOME settings](https://github.com/deadalnix/pixel-saver/issues/137), so I have been able to remove the minimise and maximise buttons by disabling them in Tweak Tool.

How do I similarly disable/remove the close (X) button?

(I guess this is the opposite of ["No close button in GNOME 3"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54866/no-close-button-in-gnome-3))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try one of the following.

### 1. Tweak Pixel Saver code

You may tweak **Pixel Saver** to get rid of the buttons by following these steps:

1. Go to Pixel Saver directory viz. `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/pixel-saver@deadalnix.me/` (if it is installed locally).
2. Open the `extension.js` file with a text editor.
3. Look for the three lines

   - `Buttons.init(extensionMeta);`
   - `Buttons.enable();`
   - `Buttons.disable();`

   and comment them out by putting `//` before the lines (i.e. change `Buttons.init(extensionMeta);` to `//Buttons.init(extensionMeta);` and so on).
4. Save the `extension.js` file.
5. Restart GNOME shell by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and then entering `r` and pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>.

**Note:** These changes to the `extension.js` file will most probably be overwritten by each update of the extension.

This will get rid of window buttons for maximised windows from the "*Activities*" bar at the top. I believe that's what you wish to achieve.

### 2. GNOME settings

If you want to get rid of **all** the buttons from all windows, run the following command in Terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout :
```

### 3. Use a different extension

[No Title Bar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1267/no-title-bar/) is a fork of Pixel Saver that specifically implements this functionality.

Comment: About the solution #2: is this persistent? If so, how do I turn it back on in case I want my buttons back? Also, it doesn't seem to work for me on Fedora+i3wm, do you know why that may be?

Comment: @BłażejMichalik You can always fallback to the default option with `reset` (in this case `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout`).