# How to change the desktop back to normal (Gnome or Unity, or Wayland)

Tags: desktop-environments, ubuntu-gnome, 22.10, desktop-icons

Recently, there has been some incident, and I searched through online to finally get my computer back (from not being able to open to now posting this question from the same Ubuntu machine)
while I was doing that, I might've tried lots of things seemed to be correct, even including reinstalling the gnome server ...etc.

Now my desktop looks different, and I cannot see the taskbar unless I hit on the Windows button on the keyboard.

basically even the minimize, maximize buttons also disappeared.

How can I restore back to Ubuntu's default look and feel? (the 'default' look and feel when we just install the system brand new, without losing any of the files and possibly keeping the software as they are in working condition)

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Since no one knows the many things you may have done there is no info here that can be used to offer any help.

Comment: If you are really running 20.10 as the tag suggests you have a different issue. Ubuntu 20.10 has only nine months of support, until July 2021. It is now off topic on this site.

Comment: Thank you @David for your comment. I know I could not provide as much info as needed due to limited knowledge with Ubuntu, but I thought I posted on the askubuntu.com website, not sure its off topic because only 9 months of support left. either way, if we cannot get some community support here on this page, I don't know where I can. thank you for your comment anyway.

Comment: It is off topic because support stopped in July 2021

Comment: Now, it's completely clear, and I just realized I tag the wrong version. My Ubuntu is latest version (which I believe 22.10, before 23.04 comes up pretty soon). Please share any info you happen to know on how to fix 22.10 (current latest version back to normal). my apologies about that error I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Run the following command to restore your window buttons (unmaximize and minimize):

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout
```

I found this solution in [a comment by user @pomsky](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948313/how-do-i-hide-disable-close-buttons-for-gnome-windows#comment1793996_948321) to another question about hiding/disabling these buttons.

#### Run the following command to restore the "Hot Corner" to activate the Activities menu:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-hot-corners true
```

I found this solution in the RedHat documentation: [Disabling the hot corner functionality on GNOME Shell](https://Disabling%20the%20hot%20corner%20functionality%20on%20GNOME%20Shell) but I changed the command from `false` to `true`.

---

##### Alternatively, you can use the system settings to enable the Hot Corner:

- open your System Settings
- select Multitasking (from the menu on the left)
- toggle the switch for "Hot Corner"

##### You can also use the dconf tool instead of the gsettings command.

For example:

- From your Activities menu, search for "dconf tool" or "dconf".
- Open the dconf tool application and navigate to **org** > **gnome** > **desktop** >  . . . until you see the window manager, window, or button settings.
- Toggle the buttons you would like to enable or disable under the button layout setting.

Comment: Similarly, you could also use the dconf tool app to enable the hot corner. Open dconf and then navigate to org > gnome > desktop > interface  and then toggle the setting for "enable hot corners".